# Como solucionar este error × TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createContext is not a function?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createContext is not a function
./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/TransitionGroupContext.js
```

Estoy usando por primera vez la librería React Transition Group para manejar animaciones y tengo ese error al hacer un simple test

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Transition from 'react-transition-group/Transition';

import './App.css';
import Modal from './components/Modal/Modal';
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop/Backdrop';
import List from './components/List/List';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    showBlock: false,
  };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>React Animations</h1>
        <button
          className="Button"
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState(prevState => ({ showBlock: !prevState.showBlock }))
          }
        >
          Toggle
        </button>
        <br />
        <Transition in={this.state.showBlock} timeout={300}>
          {state => <p>{state}</p>}
        </Transition>
        <Modal show={this.state.modalIsOpen} closed={this.closeModal} />
        <Backdrop show={this.state.modalIsOpen} />
        <button onClick={this.showModal} className="Button">
          Open Modal
        </button>
        <h3>Animating Lists</h3>
        <List />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```